# HTML/CSS: scroll bar appears below HTML elements

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

In Chrome and Safari, the vertical scroll bar appears below HTML content on the page, like so:

[image: scroll bar appears below header]

I fiddled with `::-webkit-scrollbar`, but the closest i could get was change the scroll bar width to `0px`. The div of that section is:

```
.displayContent { min-width:620px; width:100%; height:auto; overflow:hidden; }
```

This occurs in Safari (but not mobile Safari on iOS) and Chrome. Firefox is fine. I also tried fiddling with overflow as well, but could not get the results i wants.

Suggestions?

Comment: Very odd. Can you post some HTML?

Comment: Currently there's way too much code to post, but there is alot of overflow that's happening. Sorry if this isn't as helpful

Comment: Do you have any `transform` styles? I have seen examples where transformed things are drawn over everything else, including scrollbars, and even out of iframes, in some browsers.

Comment: Did you apply the scrollbar to the page yourself? It looks like an issue that could come up when you apply a scrollbar to an individual element that allows other elements to overlap it

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same issue, was this ever solved? There seems to be next to nothing so much as mentioning it anywhere online...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
html, body { 
    height:100%; 
    width:100%; 
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Had a similar Problem.

The Problem is in the html{}

If you use something like this

```
 html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
 }
```

Than the overlay effect on the scrollbar apears.
Remove the overflow on the style for the html and put it into the body styling and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Saw this today only reproducing in Safari. The issue was that I had children of the scrollable element with the following CSS (to force GPU compositing):

`-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
backface-visibility: hidden;
transform: translateZ(0px);`

The solution was to ass the same code to the container (the element with `overflow:auto;`), which caused the browser to draw everything correctly (with the scroll bar over the content).