# Solutions for clickable elements hidden beneath scrollbar on mobile Safari

Tags: html, css, ios, safari

Here's the issue:
There's a hamburger menu on the top right corner of a mobile website I'm building.

On mobile Safari, if you scroll down the page, then back up the page, the scrollbar scrubber ends up covering part of the hamburger button. If you're not precise with your press on the button, you end up touching the scrollbar instead of the hamburger, and the hamburger doesn't open.

This isn't an issue on mobile Chrome because the scrollbar ends below the nav.

What's the best way to address this issue? Assuming the client isn't open to moving/changing the hamburger.

Comment: Tweaking the hamburger really would be one of the best solutions - make it larger, or add padding to the top and right

Comment: You might also have the solution to set the nav as fix position when scroll bar is on the top of the screen, in that case, you might have the navbar priority on the scroll

Comment: @CertainPerformance This feels like a straightforward solution, but unacceptable by client. The actual touch box is already much larger than the hamburger itself, so pretty accommodating. The main issue is if you touch with the pad of your finger from the edge of the screen, the main point of contact is too far right.

Comment: @MaxiGui The nav/nav elements are already fixed; scrollbar still takes priority for touch.

Comment: @ttilde it is question from a person that add the opposite problem of you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087323/html-css-scroll-bar-appears-below-html-elements Let me know if it helps. I guess, it is thanks to the min-width and overflow hidden

Comment: Here another solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59335648/trying-to-make-nav-bar-hidden-when-in-mobile-view